# Swiftui navigation view principal item on detail view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

i have swiftui application for min target ios 15. In my ux design is logo on every page. on ios 16 following good

```
NavigationView {
   List(data, id: \.id) { item in
     DetailKeyComponent(item: item, withArrow: true)
           .overlay {
              NavigationLink(destination: AppTabMyKeysDetailView(item: item),
                             label: { EmptyView() })
                            .opacity(0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        HeaderLogoComponent(dark: true)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

with simple detail code

```
ZStack {
        Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
        
        VStack {
            Text("tab-key-detail")
                .foregroundColor(Color("ColorFontDark"))
                .font(.custom("Roboto", fixedSize: 24))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding([.top], 25)
            
            DetailKeyComponent (item: viewModel.item, withArrow: false)
                .padding([.leading], 20)
                .padding([.top], 10)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 15)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                HeaderLogoComponent(dark: true)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: viewModel.load)
    }
```

but principal item on detail is missing for ios 15 can you help ?